# How can I set the lifetime for a reference which isn't an argument of the function?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm trying to compile this code. The function `get_lines` must generate a vector of `Line`s, push a new line to it and return this vector.

```
fn main() {
    let begin_point = Point{x:100, y:100};
    let end_point = Point{x:300, y:100};

    let lines = get_lines( &begin_point, &end_point);
}

fn get_lines<'a>(begin_point: &'a Point, end_point: &'a Point) -> Vec<Line<'a>>
{
    let mut lines: Vec<Line> = vec![];
    let middle_color = Color{r:0,g:0,b:0};

    let line = Line {
        begin_point: begin_point,
        end_point: end_point,
        color: &middle_color,
    };

    lines.push(line);
    lines
}

struct Color<> {r:i32, g:i32, b:i32}
struct Point {x:i32, y:i32}
struct Line<'a> {
    begin_point: &'a Point,
    end_point: &'a Point,
    color: &'a Color
}
```

Compilation fails with this error:

```
src\main.rs:16:17: 16:29 error: `middle_color` does not live long enough
src\main.rs:16         color: &middle_color,
                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~
src\main.rs:9:1: 21:2 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 9:0...
src\main.rs: 9 {
src\main.rs:10     let mut lines: Vec<Line> = vec![];
src\main.rs:11     let middle_color = Color{r:0,g:0,b:0};
src\main.rs:12
src\main.rs:13     let line = Line {
src\main.rs:14         begin_point: begin_point,
               ...
src\main.rs:11:43: 21:2 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 1 at 11:42
src\main.rs:11     let middle_color = Color{r:0,g:0,b:0};
src\main.rs:12
src\main.rs:13     let line = Line {
src\main.rs:14         begin_point: begin_point,
src\main.rs:15         end_point: end_point,
src\main.rs:16         color: &middle_color,
               ...
error: aborting due to previous error
```

How can I set the lifetime for a reference which isn't an argument of the function? Or is the logic of code wrong?

Comment: Your question can be answered, but it'd good to know what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the error, because when `get_lines()` returns, `middle_color` goes out of scope and gets freed. You'd get a dangling pointer in the vector if this doesn't happen.

If you really want to use a reference in `Line` to `color`, you can instantiate it in the `main` function and pass a reference to it into `get_lines()`, e.g:

```
fn get_lines<'a>(begin_point: &'a Point, end_point: &'a Point, middle_color: &'a Color) -> Vec<Line<'a>>
{
...
}
```

But if you do this, you can even create your `Line` in `main` and move that into `get_lines()`.

Comment: It's not full code. I tried to make it simple. In original `middle_color` taking from other function. And in future it will creating in the loop. This is [full code](https://gist.github.com/HaruAtari/4a8f7d98f08248835479).

Comment: In this case I wouldn't use references in `Line`,  because you loose a lot of flexibility. `Point` and `Color` are `Copy` types, you just have to derive the implementation. So I'd make `Line` contain real values.

Comment: What do you mean? Created copy of `Line` and send ref to this copy into struct? Or make fields of `Line` struct as real-values?

Comment: The latter - use real values in the fields of Line. E.g: `struct Line { p1: Point, p2:Point, c: Color}`.